# Apache server not going online on ubuntu

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, server, port

I have done all steps to make my apache2 server to work online but failed to do .  My isp has not blocked port 80 and i have also forwarded my routers port 80.  Please help me . 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your website is accessible in your LAN, the most probable issue is coming from your nat translation rule.

Also verify your local firewall on your webserver with :

```
sudo iptables -L
```